# How can I match any word or any phrase in between quotes except for AND or OR using regex?

Tags: java, regex

Say, I have the following input:

`word1 AND word2 AND 'word3 word4' OR word5AND OR 'word6 OR word7'`

I want to match everything that is a word (excluding AND and OR) and everything in between brackets.

So for the example, I want the following matches:

- `word1`
- `word2`
- `word3 word4`
- `word5AND`
- `word6 OR word7`

I have the following regex almost does the trick:

`([\"'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1|(\b\w*[-']\w*\b)|(\w*)\b(?:(?!AND|OR)\w)+\b`

The only failure is that it does not target `word5AND`. I want to use this in combination with `replaceAll`

Hope someone can help me fix this!

See also: https://regex101.com/r/ZJOlaN/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of a slight mod of your excellent regex.
Basically just added boundary's `\b` around the negative assertion for *AND / OR* .
Note - Especially liked this sequence here `(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?` to overcome the escaping
of an unknown delimiter. I've used this myself.

```
([\"'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1|(\b\w*[-']\w*\b)|(\b(?!(?:AND|OR)\b)\w+\b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/uzkDQB/1

```
   ( [\"'] )                     # (1)
   (?:
      (?=
         ( \\? )                       # (2)
      )
      \2 . 
   )*?
   \1 
 | ( \b \w* [-'] \w* \b )        # (3)
 | (                             # (4 start)
      \b 
      (?!
         (?: AND | OR )
         \b 
      )
      \w+ 
      \b 
   )                             # (4 end)
```

Comment: Since this answer should benefit everyone it would be helpful if you would explain the regex in detail.